# Blurred shapes when using CanvasAPI and StyledComponent in React

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

When setting width and height of canvasAPI with StyledComponent, the shapes were blurred.

```js
///jsx
<Canvas ref={canvasRef} width="1000px" height="600px"></Canvas>;

//styled-component
const Canvas = styled.canvas`  border: 1px solid black;`;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXvp8.png)
good output

```js
///jsx
<Canvas ref={canvasRef} width="1000px" height="600px"></Canvas>;

//styled-component
const Canvas = styled.canvas`  border: 1px solid black;`;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRFDr.jpg)
bad output

I created a canvas with the same size. It seems to me that the canvas is enlarged and blurred. What is the reason?

Comment: When the image is blurred that means that the width/height of the canvas is smaller than the width/height you have set in CSS. You posted 2 identical code samples. The bug is probably in some code that you did not post.